# ¿Cómo programar para IOS desde Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, macos

Podria ser con un emulador de IPad, tengo entendido que se puede descargar swift desde ahi. Y despues para subirla al App Store tendria que pasarla a una mac verdad?

Comment: en serio.. quien es el que le dio -1? Que gente mas toxica, si no lo ponen cmo les gusta le dan -1. :/

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, como dices a la final si la quieren en la tienda necesitas una Mac si o si.

Para programar iOS en Windows puedes usar:

-Adobe Flex o
-Xamarín

Igual como dije, si o si necesitas una Mac a la final.

Saludos

Comment: Se podria tambien con react-native?

Comment: SI, podria ser, este tuto lo vi hace tiempo y entendi mucho, osea me ayudo a la logica y como usarlo, ahora despues tienes que adaptarlo a lo que necesitas. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLgJreGpfyM

Comment: Esta en ingles, pero si colocas cuidado te servira

Comment: Genial, gracias, le echare un ojo para ver :P